# Convert json list to data frame

Tags: r, json, list, dataframe

I am having an issue converting a json file to a data frame.
I use jsonlite and fromJSON() function with also unlist() function but I cannot manage to get the data in the data model I want.

Json file is structured this way:

```
{"JOHN":["AZ","YZ","ZE","ZR","FZ"],"MARK":["FZ","JF","FS"],"LINDA":["FZ","RZ","QF"]}
```

And I would like to have a data frame similar to this:

```
NAME GROUP
JOHN  AZ
JOHN  YZ
JOHN  ZE
JOHN  ZR
JOHN  FZ
MARK  FZ
MARK  JF
MARK  FS
...
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `fromJSON` from `jsonlite` to get a `list` of `key/value` vectors, convert that to a two column data.frame with `stack`, rearrange the columns and change the column names (if needed).

```
library(jsonlite)
setNames(stack(fromJSON(str1))[2:1], c("NAME", "GROUP"))
#    NAME GROUP
#1   JOHN    AZ
#2   JOHN    YZ
#3   JOHN    ZE
#4   JOHN    ZR
#5   JOHN    FZ
#6   MARK    FZ
#7   MARK    JF
#8   MARK    FS
#9  LINDA    FZ
#10 LINDA    RZ
#11 LINDA    QF
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '{"JOHN":["AZ","YZ","ZE","ZR","FZ"],"MARK":["FZ","JF","FS"],"LINDA":["FZ","RZ","QF"]}'
```

Comment: Wow... works like a charm ! Could you just explain me the bracket [2:1] ?

Comment: @ML_Enthousiast  It is just to rearrange the columns.  By default, `stack` returns the key column second, I changed the column order so that 1st column is 2nd and 2nd first